# Passing value from QueryString into Index action of controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a querystring like this:

```
http://localhost:2563/Skill?Months=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12&SelectedMonth=8&Year=2016,2017,2018&SelectedYear=2016&....
```

And I want to pass Months, SelectedMonth, Year, SelectedYear value into Index() of controller (Index is a function takes 0 argument).
And another issue, after Index function completed, I want binding function (in javascript) to run to bind value into dropdownlist by the SelectedMonth, SelectedYear in querystring

Please help. This function helps access the Views by QueryString (not through my website)
Many thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a free coding site where you can jump on and ask for things to be done. Please show your work first so that we can collaborate.

Comment: Yeah, I just newbie and have to learn more, so ask is a best learning way I think. Thanks for your comment. I will try to answer as much as question I can to get collaborated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index(List<int> Months,int SelectedMonth,List<int> Year, int Year)
{

}
```

or use `Reqest.QueryString`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var months=Reqest.QueryString["Months"];
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Comment: _Index is a function takes 0 argument_

Comment: you can use `Request.QueryString`

Answer (score 1):

First, the action name is wrong. you should use the following,

> http://localhost:2563/index?Months=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12&SelectedMonth=8&Year=2016,2017,2018&SelectedYear=2016&...

instead of

> http://localhost:2563/Skill?Months=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12&SelectedMonth=8&Year=2016,2017,2018&SelectedYear=2016&....

second,
You need to pass some parameters. 
Here is how:

```
public ActionResult Index(List<int> Months,int SelectedMonth,List<int> Year, int Year)
{

}
```

remember to pass values as you wish to work with them. if you don't, you will face some error. use try catch block to prevent and handle exceptions.

You may also face exception accessing the web page. try to put optional parameter instead of using the above one.

```
 public ActionResult Index(List<int>? Months,int? SelectedMonth,List<int>? Year, int? Year)
    {

    }
```

Comment: action name may be change by add new route redirect to index directly

Comment: he was talking about index action in the question. So, suggested him to use index.

Comment: I just use /Skill, it call index action.

Comment: ok got it :D . I thought you might be hitting it wrongly. btw, optional parameter would be used here. if not passed, it won't hurt the action to execute

Comment: I think it is better. And how to bind the dropdown list after index function is done.

Comment: are you using any model? if you are, you can easily pass them to model and use them by JS pageload event. why are you using js to get the selected? If there is no particular requirement using Razor syntax to bind selected value would be wise

Comment: Because I did not use any Model in this context. Just directly use QueryString values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get parameters from here `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString`